# Echo expression in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been trying to print maximal depth of directory but I can't figure out how to print the results in the format "Maximal depth: xxx"

```
    dir_depth() {
      cd "$1"
      maxdepth=0
      for d in */.; do
        [ -d "$d" ] || continue
        depth=`dir_depth "$d"`
        maxdepth=$(($depth > $maxdepth ? $depth : $maxdepth))
      done
      echo $((1 + $maxdepth)) #this line is problem
    }

dir_depth "$@"
```

If I try to do it like

```
    foo=$((1 + $maxdepth))
    echo "Maximal depth: " $foo
```

then I get an error

```
Max depth: 1: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "depth: 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all the parts, just need to assemble them correctly;

```
echo "Maximal depth:  $((1 + maxdepth))"
```

For example:

```
x=5
echo "Max $((1+x))"
```

Results in `Max 6` being printed.

Comment: problem is when i write it like that i am getting this error line "32: Maximal depth: 1: expression recursion level exceeded (error token is "depth: 1")"

Comment: well i am still getting syntax error, echo `"Max $((1 + maxdepth))"` and then i get this error `line 32: Max 1 > 0 ? Max 1 : 0: syntax error in expression (error token is "1 > 0 ? Max 1 : 0")`

Comment: I have no access to line 32 to help you understand your next problem. If this has fixed your echo problem, you are likely onto the next issue in your script.

Comment: line 32 is this line `maxdepth=$(($depth > $maxdepth ? $depth : $maxdepth))` in op